# How can eliminate the line that counts everything [COUNT function in SQL]

Tags: sql, count, row

I was running a code where I needed to see the top 10 results in a table. Unfortunately, I am with one more row that I was expecting.

```
SELECT 
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

My results was the following:
[Result after the query][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCu7W.png

Is there any way I can eliminate row 1 from my query?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration
  FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
 where start_station_name is not null
 GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
 ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
 LIMIT 10
```